# Download xls file with CasperJS/PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, excel, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to scrape a website that is containing an excel file that I want to download.
The download part works, but when I open the file I see a forbidden message that is saying that downloading of the file is not allowed.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    domain = 'http://www.fagg-afmps.be',
    fs = require('fs');

phantom.casperPath = 'C:/casperjs';
phantom.injectJs('C:/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js');

fs.changeWorkingDirectory("C:\Projects\Inactive medicins");

var casper = require('casper').create({
    pageSettings: {
        webSecurityEnabled: false,
        verbose: true
    }
});

casper.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36")

casper.start(domain + '/nl/');

casper.then(function(){
    var xlsLinkOriginal = this.evaluate(function(){
        return $('.XLSLink').attr('href');
    });

    var filename = xlsLinkOriginal.substring(xlsLinkOriginal.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var linkPath = domain + xlsLinkOriginal.substring(0,xlsLinkOriginal.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    try{
        //file information
        this.echo('filename: ' + unescape(filename));
        this.echo('path: ' + linkPath + unescape(filename));

        this.download(linkPath, unescape(filename));
    }catch(e){
        this.echo(e);
    }
}); 
casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('Done.').exit();
});
```

Do I need to add some headers to get it working? Or what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I made a mistake. I've put verbose in the wrong place and didn't see any errors. It is working now with this code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    domain = 'http://www.fagg-afmps.be',
    fs = require('fs');

phantom.casperPath = 'C:/casperjs';
phantom.injectJs('C:/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js');

//working directory
fs.changeWorkingDirectory("C:\Projects\Inactive medicins");

var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',//needed for debugging
    pageSettings: {
        webSecurityEnabled: false,

    }
});

casper.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36")

casper.start(domain + '/nl/');

casper.then(function(){
    var xlsLink = this.evaluate(function(){
        return $('.XLSLink').attr('href');
    });

    var filename = xlsLink.substring(xlsLink.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var linkPath = domain + xlsLink.substring(0,xlsLink.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    try{
        //file information
        this.echo('filename: ' + unescape(filename));
        this.echo('path: ' + linkPath + unescape(filename));

        //Here was the mistake. It just needs the url that it needs 
        //to download and the path where it needs to store it on the
        //computer.
        this.download(xlsLink, fs.workingDirectory + "/test.xls");
    }catch(e){
        this.echo(e);
    }
}); 
casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('Done.').exit();
});
```

Comment: Can you please make clearer what the issue was? I don't want to do a visual diff between the question and the answer.

Comment: I've put in comments to show what was wrong and removed the snippets